# divide an array and save in the variable php

Tags: php, arrays

This code starts the array from 0 and prints 2 to 2 for the last time

This variable can be sent to the telegram

Unfortunately, every time you need to complete the process, you must refresh the code

Is there a better way to split an array and store it in variable 2 to 2?

```
$MyArray = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','J');

$ii = file_get_contents("1.txt");  //first stage = 0

$ii2 = file_get_contents("2.txt");  //first stage = 1

for ($i=$ii; $i <= $ii2; $i++)
{
    $Output .= $MyArray[$i]."<br>";

    if($i == $ii2)
    {
        echo $Output;
        file_put_contents("1.txt",$ii+2);
        file_put_contents("2.txt",$ii2+2);
        // sendMessage $Output ...
    }
}
if ($ii2 >= COUNT($MyArray))
{
    file_put_contents("1.txt",0);
    file_put_contents("2.txt",1);
}
```

For example with array_chunk
But return 2 to 2 in the variable and print it

Comment: It may just be me, but I have no clue what it is you're trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: I am sorry that this question is unclear

But i want

array('A','B','C','D','E','F','J');
...

echo $Output; // Output : A B -> C D -> E F -> J // next level === ->

Comment: Loop the array and for every loop add the next key's value to the current one, and then skip a value in the loop (so you only do this every other value as required).

Comment: Why can you not use `array_chunk()`?

Comment: Why do you even have file functions mentioned in your code snippet? Are they really necessary? When asking a question, you should provide a minimal viable code, stripped of all extra stuff that has nothing to do with your problem. It is _very_ unclear what your code should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code counts the contents of the array and divides it into category 2 or any number you want. It then prints each category in the variable or can send the message to the telegram.

```
<?php
$MyArray = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','J');
$Array2 = array_chunk($MyArray,2);
for($i = 0; $i < count($Array2); $i++)
{
    for($c = 0; $c < count($Array2[$i]); $c++)
    {
        $text .= $Array2[$i][$c]."<br>";
    }
    // sendMessage ...
    echo $text."<br>";
    $text = "";
}
?>
```

This is the answer to my question.

Comment: It would be helpful to the OP or any other reader if you can at least add a brief explanation of your code. :)

Comment: The code counts the contents of the array and divides it into category 2 or any number you want
It then prints each category in the variable or can send the message to the telegram.

Once you run the code, you will notice